# GridView of Items in an InputMethod Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, ime

I have a standard ime working fine with regular keyboard xml files and a regular KeyboardView.

I would now like to add a button that switches to a GridView of images.

How would I get a GridView to pop-up in the keyboard area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to return a LinearLayout that held the GridView when onCreateInputView() was called. Now I can freely switch between KeyboardViews and GridViews.